# How to structure database of an application that will utilize multiple datasources for its models?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating an application that will use at minimum two different API for data of its models. For example, I'll have an entity / model of a person. The data for this person comes at minimum two different API and more may be relevant in the future. For example, email and phonenumber may come from one data source and first name and second name from another.

How would one structure an database for this, that is flexible enough to handle adding / removing of the "data sources".

I initially though of an database structure looking like this:

[Person]
- ID
- FirstName
- LastName
- Email
- PhoneNumber

[Person_FIRST_SOURCE]
- Person_ID
- Person_FIRST_SOURCE_ID

[Person_SECOND_SOURCE]
- Person_ID
- Person_SECOND_SOURCE_ID

Which I then would be able to in the data synchronization script to look up what "Person" entity in my database, the current iterating person from the source represents. This would allow me to easily connect/add more sources as I go.

EDIT: I would like to add that it's not always that Person A exist within both sources of data.

EDIT 2:  The main question is not really dependent on the "Person" model. This could have been any type of model; Book, School, Company etc. Just some form of model, where its data comes from multiple sources.

Comment: What are you really trying to model? Things like "persons", or things more like "claims of facts about persons"?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Well it's employees of an organization, really. But the main question is noy really depedent on the model. This could have been any type of model; Book, School, Company etc. Just some form of model, where its data comes from multiple sources.

Comment: My question still stands. Your proposed structure says "One or more attributes of person having id 'n' came from source having id 'm'." So your proposed structure can handle any number of sources per person, but it doesn't seem very useful.